# Safari is not acknowledging the "required" attribute. How to fix it?

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, required

```html
<form id="customerForm">
    <label>
        First Name:
        <input id="firstName" required />
    </label>
    <label>
        Social Security Number:
        <input id="ssn" required pattern="^d{3}-d{2}-d{4}$"
            title="Expected pattern is ###-##-####" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When I try that document in Chrome, it accepts the conditions and shows the error, as expected.

But when I try that document in Safari, it shows no error.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

At this time, Safari doesn't support the "required" input attribute.
http://caniuse.com/#search=required

To use the 'required' attribute on Safari, You can use '[webshim](https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim)'

1 - Download webshim

2 - Put this code :

```
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="js-webshim/minified/polyfiller.js"></script> 

    <script> 
        webshim.activeLang('en');
        webshims.polyfill('forms');
        webshims.cfg.no$Switch = true;
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have decided to use it from the CDN instead, you can find a minified version here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/webshim

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about Webshim, which solved the problem instantly. Sadly found two duplicate questions with in principle good answers, but not close to your solution; now flagged them and hopefully lead more people to this post/answer!

Comment: I referred to your answer in an answer of myself (and even copied your code example as a 'kickstart' for other people) and I just got asked what the line 'webshims.cfg.no$Switch = true;' exactly does. Could you explain to me please? :)

Comment: webshim.activeLang('en'); <- What if we are using another language?

Comment: @detoro84 set the language you want to use as described here: http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/forms.html#Locale-Settings

Answer (score 7):

Currently, Safari doesn’t yet emit any error messages for required values in form fields that the user has not provided (nor for invalid values the user has put into form fields). But you can enable it by using hacks or a polyfill. See [HTML5 Form Validation Fallback (without a library)](http://blueashes.com/2013/web-development/html5-form-validation-fallback/) for a lightweight hack that enables it, and see [h5Validate](https://github.com/ericelliott/h5Validate) for a jQuery-based polyfill plugin.

Comment: Webshim is a nice library but if all you're aiming to do is solve for the OP, the linked "HTML5 Form Validation Fallback" is perfect at about 20 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

The required attribute should be available in [Safari 10.1 and newer](https://webkit.org/blog/7099/html-interactive-form-validation/).